# Bootstrap Popovers in php

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have popovers on a page, and they work just fine. The JS is called from a separate file. However, I have popovers on a dynamically generated table via php on the page, and using the same logic as above, they do not. After browsing the web for answers, I am stuck. Help?

Code:

```
print('
    <div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody class="list">
                <tr>
                    <th>Reference<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-content="test." data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-question-circle pull-right"></i></a><a href="#" data-sort="order" class="sort"><i class="fa fa-sort pull-right"></i></a></th>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the JS:

```
// Popup functionality
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({'trigger':'hover'});
});
```

I assume that if the JS functionality is called when the page loads, that it is not initializing when the dynamic php is brought into the page. So am I correct in assuming it has to be added to the php somewhere?

Comment: Add your js code inside $(document).ready(), so it starts working only upon dom completion. Are you sure your jquery selector and code inside is correct?

Comment: Yes. And it is inside a document.ready. I just could not post it here because the js file is 7000 lines long. Im just assuming that because the dom has already been loaded, and that the table is being injected into the page dynamically with php, thats why its not working. The page has already loaded all the JS.

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean by dynamicly injected, but if you dynamicly add data after page load, you need to bind that element . In old days it would be with jquery live() function, now its with on()